# Return order details in REST API Magento-2

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, rest-api

I am writing a custom API which will use a customer token in authorization header and will able to fetch the order details.

Below is my code:

File : CustomerOrderRepositoryInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Api;


interface CustomerOrderRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Get Customer Order.
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $customerId
     * @param int $orderId
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface Order interface.
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getOrder($customerId, $orderId);
}
```

File : CustomerOrderRepository.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model\Resource;

use Vendor\Modulename\Api\CustomerOrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class CustomerOrderRepository implements CustomerOrderRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository
     */
    private $orderRepository;



    /**
     * CustomerOrderRepository constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Get Customer Order.
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @param int $orderId
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface Order interface.
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getOrder($customerId, $orderId)
    {
        /**
        * Here I have put some custom checks before proceeding to fetch the order details and 
        * based on that I am getting the $customerOrderId from my custom table.
        */

        if($customerOrderId == $orderId) {
            /** Here I am passing the correct order ID. 
              *I am able to get the details with admin token for same orderId.*/
            $orderDetails = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
            return $orderDetails;
        }else {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('There is no order with number "%1" is associated.',$orderId));
        }
    }
}
```

File : webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/vendor/orders/:orderId" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Modulename\Api\CustomerOrderRepositoryInterface" method="getOrder"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
</routes>
```

I am getting the error below in the response. (I tried using use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface too)

```
{
    "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "orderId",
        "fieldValue": "17"
    }
}
```

How I can fetch the order details in this scenario?

Comment: you need to declare the route in the webapi.xml first ie, /rest/v1/foo/boo/:vendorId/:orderId

Comment: I have edited my question added my webapi.xml. Btw it gives "Request does not match any route" error if I didn't specify the routes in webapi.xml.

Comment: try something like this,

:vendorId = url param,
:orderId = url param

vars name need to match with interface params method declaration

 <route url="/V1/pos/foo/:vendorId/:orderId" method="GET">
        <service class="vendor_name\module_name\Api\FooInterface" method="getById" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="vendor_module::getById_acl" />
        </resources>
    </route>

Comment: I didn't get any reference link in your previous comment :)

Comment: heres is a good example for a new api endpoint: https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/

Comment: I am able to get the values in function correctly see my error shows "fieldValue": "17" so I am passing 17 as orderId. Customer Id I am getting from token itself. The error I am getting is from $entity = $this->metadata->getNewInstance()->load($id); this line in file /magento/module-sales/Model/OrderRepository.php

Comment: whats about injecting \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory and then try to load via order model ? 

construct: \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $oFacotry
getById method : 
   - $order = oFacotry->create()
   - $order->getResource()->load($order, $theID);
   - if !$order->getId() throw some \Exception

Comment: I think I should go with that only. Just wondering why the public method from OrderRepository is not working for me. As the same method is working if I hit "rest/V1/orders/:orderId" which is magento's core API to fetch the order details.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the same error. Is there any restriction on using order model in the custom rest api? Or do I need to change any permissions/configuration/settings some where?

Comment: Is anyone got the solution.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Plugin/Authorization.php below code is throwing the error.

```
public function aroundLoad(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $order,
    $value,
    $field = null
) {
    $result = $proceed($order, $value, $field);
    if (!$this->isAllowed($order)) {
        throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField('orderId', $order->getId());
    }
    return $result;
}
```

$this->isAllowed method checks against USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER. As I am passing the different customer token which is need of my project, it's throwing the error.

Comment: I am getting order details for customer with the same customer token, But still I got the same error like mentioned above.